# jQuery Ajax cannot send List of objects to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to send two parameters to a MVC controller method to save some information to my MS SQL Server database through an Ajax request. My method receives an int, and a List of complex type objects. The method however, is only able to receive the int parameter, and receives a null for the List.

Below is the jQuery script I used to send the Ajax request with both 'ReferenceNo' and 'Lots' as data for this request.

jQuery Script (Ajax)

```
paramReferenceNo = 2;
paramLots = JSON.stringify(paramLots);
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: serverpath + '/Home/Save_Lots',
  data: "{'paramReferenceNo':'" + paramReferenceNo + "', 'paramLots':'" + paramLots + "'}",
  success: function (data) {
    alert('Saved!');
  }
});
```

Below is the MVC method that does the saving of data into SQL Server. In debugger mode, when the Ajax request is fired, I can see from my breakpoint that `paramReferenceNo`' gets the int 2 but the 'paramLots' gets null (Count= 0).

Save_Lot (MVC_Controller method)

```
public void Save_Lots(int paramReferenceNo, List<SalesProd_Lots> paramLots) {
  using (SalesProdDBContext CDC = new SalesProdDBContext()) {
    // Logic to save to database here....
  }
}
```

The request returns a response of 200 -OK. Below is the 'Request Body' as taken from the IE network debugger.

Request Body

```
{'paramReferenceNo':'2', 'paramLots':'[{"ReferenceNo":1,"LotNo":"CC-1889","isActive":true},{"ReferenceNo":1,"LotNo":"CD-1891","isActive":true},{"ReferenceNo":1,"LotNo":"CE-1892","isActive":true}]'}
```

I've been looking around on similar issues here on SO, but couldn't find a solution that works for mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are passing String `paramLots = JSON.stringify(paramLots);` and trying to access it as `List`

Comment: Delete `paramLots = JSON.stringify(paramLots);` and use `data: JSON.stringify({ paramReferenceNo: paramReferenceNo, paramLots: paramLots }),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks mate, your solution did it. Mind posting your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Darin Dimitrov has added an answer showing that (the view model is not entirely necessary, but also a good idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by writing a view model that will encapsulate the needed parameters:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ParamReferenceNo { get; set; }

    public List<SalesProd_Lots> ParamLots { get; set; }
}
```

which your controller action will take as parameter:

```
public void Save_Lots(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

and then on the client side:

```
paramReferenceNo = 2;
lots = paramLots; // this could be a complex object

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    url: serverpath + '/Home/Save_Lots',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        paramReferenceNo: paramReferenceNo,
        paramLots: lots
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Saved!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the design of the application was not favoring for view models. I decided to go with the original design and do away with view models for now. Although your solution for the client side script seems to work well for my issue even with the two parameter MVC method I currently have. Thanks.